# How to plot an interaction in generalized mixed linear model with regions of significance?

Tags: data-visualization, interaction, glmm

How can I plot a region of significance of the effect of a dichotomous predictor (x2) on two levels (-1SD and +1SD) of a continuous predictor (x1), when the DV (y) is a binary variable?

The model is generalized mixed linear model:

```
M <- glmer(y ~ x1 * x2 + (x1*x2|subject) + (1|stimulus),
           family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = dataframe)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by, "region of significance"?